# Twitterizer dll

Tags: visual-web-developer, twitterizer

I am using Visual Web Developer and trying to use [Twitterizer](http://code.google.com/p/twitterizer/). I have downloaded and extracted the framework and created a reference within my project. When I run the project, the projet tells me that it cannot find TwitterRequest.cs. It appears to be looking for it on an invalid path. I don't know how to change this file path.

I have the latest build of the framework.

I have since moved the app off my MacBook which is running Parallels. On PC it works consistently. Damn Parallels.

Comment: can you add the entire error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried downloading the lastest pre-built version of the library?

I just posted version [1.0.1.99](http://twitterizer.googlecode.com/files/Twitterizer.Framework-1.0.1.99.zip). If you still have problems, please dm @[Twit_er_izer](http://twitter.com/Twit_er_izer), [submit an issue](http://code.google.com/p/twitterizer/issues/list) or email our [mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/twitterizer).